# React Native Box Shadow (Android) - Flex

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, box-shadow

I'm going to set a `BoxShadow` for a button in my app. As RN doesn’t have Shadow (except that basic `elevation`), I use [`react-native-shadow`](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) but then I have another problem!

They support:

```
const shadowOpt = {
    width:100,
    height:100,
    color:"#000",
    border:2,
    radius:3,
    opacity:0.2,
    x:0,
    y:3,
    style:{marginVertical:5}
}
```

which are:

> width: you must set the value the same as your child component
>
> height: the same as above
>
> color: the color of shadow,it doesn't support rgba now,you may use opacity
>
> border: the width of shadow , cannot less than 0
>
> radius: the same value as the "borderRadius" of chileElement
>
> opacity: the opacity of shadow
>
> x: the offsetX of shadow
>
> y: the offsetY of shadow
>
> style: the style you want to add to the wrapper box

So, I used `flex` for my button:

```
buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(6,82,221,0.70)",
    borderRadius: 5
}
```

and I **cannot** set the `width` and `height` for Shadow!

Any solutions?